# How do I install opencsv and use CSVReader in Java/Intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, opencsv

When I install com.opencsv:opencsv:5.7.0 in IntelliJ via Project Structure -> Global Libraries -> Add Maven Dependency, it installs the correct jars, but CSVReader along with the rest of opencsv is not recognized by the system. I tried downloading to the lib folder along with a few other things I found online like invalidating cache/rebuild, but nothing has worked. Any ideas on how to get opencsv working in IntelliJ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check that library is added to module dependencies "Project Structure | Modules - Dependencies"

Comment: @y.bedrov I added a screenshot of that page. It appears to be there.

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample project?

Comment: Assume it's not

Comment: Please try to remove IDE related data (.idea folder and .iml file) and reimport project again.

Comment: @y.bedrov that did not work, and I completely reinstalled IntelliJ. I updated my post with a picture of all the libraries because at this point, I am assuming it means opencsv is incompatible with another installed library. I am fairly new to IDEs since most of my schooling focused on code, not configuration. If anything helped you with learning that stuff, please let me know. Thanks!